# Why sql cannot see the column?

Tags: php, mysql

`Unknown column 'ft_template' in 'field list`

For some reason, this happens. I could print whole request and copy. So it's works if i execute it manually. But in case of php i got this error. It's here

[image]

But

```
UPDATE `portal_settings` SET `ft_template`='123' WHERE `id` = 1;
```

didn't work.

There is work. In php not.

[image]

Comment: Try in caps . . .

Comment: Where is the error? Which is the exact code your are executing in php?

Comment: @gmc the same sql in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy paste this and see if it works:

```
"UPDATE portal_settings SET ft_template='123' WHERE id = 1"
```

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''portal_settings' SET 'ft_template'='123' WHERE 'id' = 1' at line 1`

Comment: try now. Updated

Comment: You __don't__ want to use single quotes for table or column names; single quotes are for string literals

Comment: And please, show the PHP code. I assume it is because you are not setting the query in string format.

Comment: @tomSurge `Unknown column 'ft_template' in 'field list'` :>

Comment: @Fortael Are you actually connected to the correct database?

Comment: @tomSurge Yes. Funny fact: if i would not use this field, everything is okay. Without that field i have no problem. My guess may be some cache. Idk.

Comment: @tomSurge works fine. I already working with this table, Able to update, select and etc. That not my apllication. Just added one more column and... you noticed. If do not use that field in requests, then everything is okay.

Comment: wouldn't we have more info if we give this a try with PPS ?